# Terraform for_each on a list

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to do smth very basic
this is my variable file

```
test = {
  t1 = {
    top = [
        {
            port = "12"
            name = "port12"
        },
        {
            port = "123"
            name = "port123"
        }
    ]
},
  t2 = {
    top = [
        {
            port = "12"
            name = "port12"
        },
        {
            port = "123"
            name = "port123"
        }

    ]
}
```

}

```
resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "nat" {
  for_each = var.test 
  resource_group_name = var.rg.name
  loadbalancer_id     = elb.id
  name                = "ELB-XX"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = each.value.top.port
  backend_port                   = each.value.top.port
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = pip.id
}
```

I want :

- Name like ELB-T1-port12 , ELB-T2-port12 ,ELB-T1-port123 and ELB-T2-port123
- Retrieve port for frontend_port and backend_port

I can change the variable list

Answer (score 0):

Based on this configuration, you can create the azurerm_lb_nat_rule resources as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "nat" {
  for_each                    = var.test
  resource_group_name         = var.rg.name
  loadbalancer_id             = azurerm_lb.example.id
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  frontend_ip_configuration   = azurerm_network_interface.example.ip_configuration[0].id
  frontend_port               = "ELB-${each.key}-port${each.value.top[0].port}"
  backend_port                = each.value.top[0].port
  name                        = "ELB-${each.key}-port${each.value.top[0].port}"
}
```

You can read more: [The for_each Meta-Argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each)

Comment: and what about if I want to add more port and name , for this example I can only retrieve the first one